# Google Chrome Dev Tools with Android and Windows 10 getting blank page

Tags: debugging, web, windows-10, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm trying to do web debug in Google Pixel phone using Google Chrome dev tools.
Until yesterday, everything was ok. But, today I'm getting this "error":
When I click on "Inspect", I'm getting a blank page (yesterday, it worked).

[blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEAOb.png)

So, I didn't change anything, any property. What can I do to get it works?
Can you give me a hand? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled Google Chrome and then I reinstalled it.
It works for me.